# I have an error with my singleton design pattern

Tags: javascript, singleton, requirejs

I am attempting to do a singleton pattern in javascript. I am getting error message "Uncaught TypeError: route_socket.getInstance is not a function". I was wondering what am I doing wrong. I can copy and paste the pattern from a training guide and it works. But when I am trying it here, it gives the error. So I know the pattern works.

```
var route_socket = require([
    "esri/WebMap",
    "esri/views/MapView",
    "esri/layers/RouteLayer",
    "esri/rest/support/Stop"
  ],
  function(WebMap, MapView, RouteLayer, Stop) { //singleton design pattern
    var instance;

    class RouteSocket {#
      apiKey;

      constructor() {
        this.#apiKey = token.getAttribute("token");
        this.routeUrl = "https://route-api.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/Route/NAServer/Route_World";
        this.churches = [];
        this.stompClient = null;
        this.view = null;
        connect();
        this.origin = new Stop({
          geometry: {
            x: OX,
            y: OY
          },
          name: "Origin"
        })
        this.destination = new Stop({
          geometry: {
            x: DX,
            y: DY
          },
          name: "Destination"
        })
        addRandomChurch();
        addRandomChurch();
        addRandomChurch();
      }

      addRandomChurch() {
        var randomX = ((OX - DX) * Math.random()) + OX;
        var randomY = ((OY - DY) * Math.random()) + OY;
        var ChurchStop = { //Create a point
          x: randomX,
          y: randomY,
          name: "Church"
        };
        this.churchAdded(ChurchStop);
      }

      setView(view) {
        this.view = view;
        console.log("We have set the view");
        //check for churches already found and map them if they are there
        this.churches.forEach(this.addRoute(church));
      }

      connect() {

        var socket = new SockJS('/ws');
        stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
        stompClient.connect({}, this.onConnected, this.onError);
      }

      async addRoute(church) {
        let stops = [
          this.origin,
          church,
          this.destination
        ];

        let routeLayer = new RouteLayer({
          stops
        });
        view.map.add(routeLayer);
        await routeLayer.load();
        const results = await routeLayer.solve({
          apiKey
        });
        routeLayer.update(results);
        //            await view.goTo(routeLayer.routeInfo.geometry);
      }

      onConnected() {
        stompClient.subscribe('/topic/map/' + hobnobID.getAttribute("hobnobID"), this.onMessageReceived);
        synchroniseDataMapSocket.establishSocket(this);
      }

      onMessageReceived(payload) {
        var message = JSON.parse(payload.body);

        var ChurchStop = { //Create a point
          x: message.X,
          y: message.Y,
          name: "Church"
        };
        this.churchAdded(ChurchStop);
      }

      churchAdded(ChurchStop) {
        if (!this.view) {
          churches.add(ChurchStop);
          return;
        } else {
          this.addRoute(ChurchStop);
        }
        //else create stop on map
      }
    };

    function createInstance() {
      var object = new RouteSocket();
      return object;
    }

    return {
      getInstance: function() {
        if (!instance) {
          instance = createInstance();
        }
        return instance;
      }
    };
  });
route_socket.getInstance();
```

I am really grateful for any help I may receive. Thank you very much

Comment: What does `console.log(route_socket)` show? I think it's not getting set to the value returned by the function.

Comment: here is what it returns
ƒ (ca,ya,Na){return R(ca,ya,Na,0,w)}

Comment: I suspect that's coming from one of the esri files you require, you don't get the return value of the callback function.

Comment: Well it was working then it suddenly stopped. Because of your commit, I placed some console logs at random points and noticed then console log for console.log(route_socket) is playing first. Then some of the points in the middle of that request. I am thinking it could be a sync error. But if that is it, how do you do an async singleton class.

Comment: Class constructors aren't asynchronous.

Comment: Hey, Barmar, I want to say thank you very much for assisting me with this. I found my actual error. After getInstance I should not have () at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem here. It's returning a json object with reference to a function rather then the function itself. Therefore, I do not need to put the () at the end of the request.

Comment: If you don't put `()`, how do you call the function?

Comment: The function is effectively stored in a variable. So calling the variable works like calling the function. But since you are calling a variable, you do not put the () on the end. Even thou the variable is just a function. It works try it.

Comment: Pleast update the answer to show the corrected code. Can you make a working [mre] that doesn't depend on all the required `esri` files?

Comment: The only way I know of that accessing a property will call a function is if it's defined as a *getter* method.